# Create an increasing ID number in PHP

Tags: php

i would like to write a function to generate IDs for entries into a database. When the data is being created an ID in the format:

**R-20150401-1** should be created.

1. R: Fixed letter
2. 20150401: Calculated by Carbon method
3. 1: sequentially increasing number

I already get the first two components. But the increasing number is still an issue to me. There will be tickets generated in a form and I do not want to limit the number of tickets that can be generated. Therefore I think a for loop does not make sense.

This is my code right now

```
    public function generateTicketReferenceID() {
        $incidentTypeID = "R";
        $date = Carbon::now()->format('Ymd');
        $incidentID = 0;
        echo $incidentTypeID . "-" . $date . "-" . ++$incidentID;
    }
}
```

To answer the questions in the comment:

1. The rule is: append an incrementing number from 1..n to the end of the ID.
2. There are no certain numbers or number rage
3. There are no certain characters that should or should be included
4. The number should be sequential.
5. Each ticket is generated by POSTing a form and executing a function to write to the database. This function should then be called to generate the ID.

I am just thinking if it would be a good idea for a ticket system to start over with the ID on each day and when a different user logs into the system. So how could I reset the number under the following conditions when this would be my ID
**R-001-20150401-1** should be created.

1. 001: user logged into the system. When this number changes the ID should be resetted.
2. The ID resets on each day

Comment: What rules are you trying to represent in your code? Do you have certain numbers or number range that are allowed? Certain characters that should or should not be included? Do you need to keep track of numbers generated previously? Should ticket numbers be random or sequential?

Comment: You cannot `++$incidentID` until you have one to work with. You're going to have to have a way to get the last one.

Comment: Is each ticket generated in a separate php script?

Comment: Does the numbering reset on each new day?

Comment: If you're storing the records in a database, you could always us an identity field with auto increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to create your own sequence in the database in a similar manner to the way that autoincrement works. Ordinary autoincs always end up with gaps in the sequence, that is inevitable. Now in the UK  VAT invoice numbers are by law required to be in an unbroken sequence. This is so that there can be no question of tax fraud. When faced with this challenge I use the following process.

Create a table to hold the last ID issued. Just one field and one row.
When you need a new number:
LOCK the table for READ and WRITE, make sure that your transaction isolation does not allow other processes to read the table. This depends on the db and table type.
Increment the number by 1 in php.
Use the new number in your insert into the invoices table.
Then update the sequence table with the new number.
Then commit the transaction and release the lock.
The next process can then do the same.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a way to know if a previous ID exists, and what it is, to generate a incremental id.

Answer (score 1):

In your database save the date (timestamp) in one field, and make an auto-incrementing value as primary key. Then the database will handle it all automatically.

Everytime you want to print the incident ID you generate it from your SQL row: "R-" + id + date.

Comment: Good job, you just introduced a potentially fatal race condition.

Comment: You've now removed it from your answer, leaving no solution behind.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to store the number. You can do that in a file or create a extra column named incidentId. After that you can add

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY incidentId DESC LIMIT 1
```

to the function to call the last number and +1 that.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to select the last row of the DB for X date. You (could) do something like:

```
$date = date("Ymd");
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE Date = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$query->bind_param("s", $date );
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($id, $date);
if($query->num_rows !=0){
$query->fetch();
$ticketIdNumber = strstr((strstr($id,-),-);
}
else{
$ticketIdNumber = 0;
}

$incidentTypeID = "R";
$date = date('Ymd');
$ticketIdNumber++;
$newTicketId = $incidentTypeID . "-" . $date . "-" . $ticketIdNumber;
```

This would check if there is an incident today. If there isn't, it makes it incident 1... If there is, it makes it incident (last + 1)